# MacVim inserts circumflex (^) for blank spaces in GUI

Tags: vim, macvim

MacVim inserts circumflex symbols (^) and I haven't found any hint on why it does it and how to disable this. Anybody reading this, experiencing the same problem?
[image]
[image]

Comment: `:help fillchars`

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the error was that fillchars was not set correctly. Furthermore, my color scheme used the same value for both StatusLine and StatusLineNC which led MacVim to use ^ as a blank space.